# How to get the element before the element in a map for the component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im rendering Components inside a map and Im giving my components data objects which are called `post`. **This works perfectly fine**.

```
{feed.map((post, index) =>
        (
          <PostBasic post={post} key={post.id} creation={creation} />
        )
      )}
```

The Post has informations like `creationDate`, `description` ...

I want to extend each `PostBasic` with the `creationDate` of the post before in the map. First of all I thought to do something like this, but it doesn't work, weither `post[index]` or `post[index-1]`

```
{feed.map((post, index) =>
            (
              <PostBasic post={post} postBefore={post[index-1]creationDate} key={post.id} creation={creation} />
            )
          )}
```

If we have 5 elements in the map, I'm expecting the following output:

```
- PostBasic with post={post} and Date of now 
- PostBasic with post={post} and creationDate of post[0]
- PostBasic with post={post} and creationDate of post[1]
- PostBasic with post={post} and creationDate of post[2]
- PostBasic with post={post} and creationDate of post[3]
```

Comment: You'd be accessing the `[i-1]` of *feed* - not post.

Comment: the posts are saved in the feed. I tried to describe it more clear. Im already receiving the post data in each PostBasic, im just not able to receive the informations of the post before in PostBasic

Comment: the array `feed` is what you're mapping over, `post` being the current value, and `index` being its index position. I would expect that if you're mapping over feed, You'd be accessing the `i-1` of *feed* - being the array that you're mapping over. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function ComponentName({ feed }) {
  return (
    <>
        {feed.map((post, index) => {
          const postBefore =
            index == 0 ? new Date() : feed[index - 1].creationDate;
          return (
            <PostBasic
              post={post}
              postBefore={postBefore}
              key={post.id}
              creation={creation}
            />
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```

You can do something like this, you had the right idea `post[index - 1].creationDate` you missed the `dot` and it should be `feed` not `post`.

Comment: Hi there thank you for the assistance! something little is missing, if i console.log the postbefore, im getting an undefined

Comment: console.log of feed is the following: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 5, createdAt: Fri Jun 11 2021 13:53:37 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit), …}
1: {id: 4, createdAt: Fri Jun 11 2021 13:52:06 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit), …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: excuse me, I had a typo, everything works fine as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: I *did* tell you to use `feed[i-1]` Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Just map the data before it's rendering, something like this,

```
const postsWithDate = feed.map((post, i) => {
  if(i === 0) return {...post, creationDate: (new Date())};
  return {...post, creationDate: (feed[i - 1].creationDate)}
});
```

Then use this in render,

```
{postsWithDate.map((post, index) =>
    (
      <PostBasic post={post} key={post.id} creationDate={creationDate} />
    )
  )}
```

Hope it works!